# How to use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

Details:

My program is a grade book with 5 classes that are all aggregated. GradeBook has courses, Course has Categories, Category has Grades (all ArrayLists). My program also has a StateManager whose sole purpose is to return references to Objects because of the deep aggregation. In my Driver I do not create an instance of a GradeBook but a statemanager which has a static instance of a GradeBook with methods to return references.

My goal is to save all of this data to be reopened when the program is rerun.

Questions:

When I write the file all I need to do is write the StateManager object, correct? I think I've even accomplished this. I have the program create a "gradebook.data" file. Is there a way to open the .data file in a text program and see if it is writing correctly?

Where do I open the object again with inputstream? In the static main method or in the beginning of my method that initializes all of the graphics?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing `StateManager` won't do anything because you have a `static` reference to the `GradeBook`. This is in itself a code smell, but here it has the physical repercussion of not getting serialized -- only *instance* fields get serialized. So remove the `static` qualifier. You can make the `StateManager` itself a singleton and have a `static` reference to it.

However, I am still in doubt as to why you don't serialize the `GradeBook` instance. That would be a far more logical approach. We don't usually serialize service objects, but data objects, and you already have that separation.

Comment: This is because the GradeBook class has nothing in it on its own. The StateManager creates the GradeBook in its class, then can return its instance to be used in the driver.

Comment: private static final StateManager manager = new StateManager(); 
 private GradeBook gb;
 
 /**
  * Creates new StateManager object with new GradeBook.
  */
 public StateManager() 
 {
  gb = new GradeBook(); 
 }

Comment: What do you mean by make it "singleton"

Comment: If what you posted here is your real code, then the `gb` var is obviously **not** static -- contrary to your statement in the question. But either way, it is proper practice to serialize the `GradeBook` itself and adapt the `StateManager`s code as needed.

Comment: Singleton is a well-known design pattern, described originally in the "Gang of Four" book. If the code in your comment above is what you have currently, then `StateManager` is already a singleton.

Comment: Hm. So I should make it so the StateManager no longer creates an instance of GradeBook, but rather adapt it to work with an already made objecto to return instances, etc.?

Comment: Yes, that would be better design. Decouple the mechanism for creating `GradeBook` from the mechanism for querying it because they are independent.

Comment: Woah! Thanks for all your help, guys. My program is saving all its data perfectly. Of course this opened up new issues that need to be resolved, but it's nice to see it saving and restoring! In my catch block, if no file had been created yet I create a new GradeBook and otherwise I load one in. Thanks again, guys!

Comment: FYI, the etiquette at SO is to reward your helpers with upvotes and by accepting the most helpful answer. Verbal thanks are optional, though :)

Comment: Hm, I guess you get to vote up as soon as you acquire some small amount of rep points. Checked, it's 15 points.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data in somewhere "early on" in your program before it is first used. In the initialisation code of your StateManager could be one place.

I can't see why the "method that initialises all of the graphics" would be a logical place.

Answer (score 0):

No, no text editor will show you all the details as a correct text format as what you have written is bytes and your text editor wants you to provide text.

Loading objects from disk to memory - two approaches

1. Load them before hand, in the sense load them in main method, in case you dont use them your effort of loading them from disk went in vain, you used memory and CPU but didnt use it further.
2. Load them when you access them the first time called as lazy loading, so when you access the static method of your StateManager, if your object is null you will load them from disk.

Offtopic:

A [nice article](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915) which explains Serialization in detail.

Comment: Hm. I still am having problems. Here is what I did: 
At the top of the driver I have my global variables of which include StateManager manager. Then the first line of code after the variabels is manager = new StateManager(); Then following that I have my
 try {
   ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("gradebook.data"));
   manager = (StateManager) oin.readObject(); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
  } 

Which I would hope, if the file was found (it is created, I checked), it would override and now reference the object from the file. Doesn't work